# statement "int executeUpdate = prest.executeUpdate();" is throwing a SQLException

Tags: java

Have had this problem for two days. Tried everything I could think of. Greatly appreciate any help you can give me on this problem. Thanks in advance.`

```
try     {  // try get tx records
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection    ( 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brent?user=root&password=adsimysql");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); System.out.println("aaactivity3");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from " + tbtx); 
System.out.println("aaactivity4");
while (rs.next()) {  // get tx records
dbrec = rs.getInt("trec");  // get input fields from database
dbacct = rs.getInt("tacct");
dbtxtype = rs.getInt("ttype");
dbtxno = rs.getInt("ttxno");
dbamt = rs.getDouble("tamt");
dbmed = rs.getDouble("tmed");
dbsaltx = rs.getDouble("tsaltx");
dbtxdat = rs.getInt("ttxdat");
dbxmail = rs.getInt("txmail");
dbbilldat = rs.getInt("tbilldat");
System.out.println("ApplyTX " + dbacct);  // print 
//        try     {   // try write ts
//Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
/*Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection    ( 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brent?user=root&password=adsimysql");        
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();*/ 
PreparedStatement prest;
String updttx = "INSERT INTO "+ tbts + " (sacct, stype, srec, stxno, samt,         smed, sstax, stxdat, sxmail, sbilldat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
//String updttx;
 //  updttx = "INSERT INTO "+ tbts + " (sacct, stype, srec, stxno, samt,    smed, sstax, stxdat, sxmail, sbilldat) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
prest = con.prepareStatement(updttx);
System.out.println("aaactivity5 " + dbacct);
prest.setInt(1,dbacct);
prest.setInt(2,dbtxtype);
prest.setInt(3,dbrec);
prest.setInt(4,dbtxno);
prest.setDouble(5,dbamt);
prest.setDouble(6,dbmed);
prest.setDouble(7,dbsaltx);
prest.setInt(8,dbtxdat);
prest.setInt(9,dbxmail);
prest.setInt(10,dbbilldat);
System.out.println("aaactivity6 "+ dbtxtype);
int executeUpdate = prest.executeUpdate();    // this statement is throwing  SQLException
System.out.println("aaactivity7");
    } // end while  get tx records
}  // end try get tx records and build ts file      ********************************
 catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {  
}
catch(SQLException insertException) {      System.out.println("SQLexception"+dbacct+" "+dbtxtype+" "+dbrec+" "+dbtxno+"   "+dbamt+" "+dbmed+" "+dbsaltx+" "+dbtxdat+" "+dbxmail+" "+dbbilldat);
//displaySQLErrors (insertException);
}
}  // end no ts
```

Comment: Print the stacktrace in the catch block!

Comment: print the exception and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block add this line  e.printStackTrace(). Execute your code and check for the excat error.
Also what is tbts? is this table name? if this is variable where u have table name then its nit defined anywhere in ur code

Comment: I found the problem. Unmatched  data names between the file description names and the names used in the program.